# Sort in tabulator

Tags: tabulator

I have a problem with tabulator sort, when I use a one column formatter, and I multiply the value.

Sorting takes the initial value and not the value resulting from the multiplication, so the sorter is wrong.

```
formatter: function(cell, formatterParams) {
                                        var value = cell.getValue();
                                        if (cell.getRow().getData().Tipo == 'Holfuy') {
                                            value=cell.getValue()*5;
                                            return value;
                                        } else {
                                            return value;
                                        }
                                    },
```

[image]

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What are the types for the fields involved? What is doing the sorting, header, initialSort, programmatic sort?  What are the parameters for the sort? It would be really helpful if you could set up a fiddle to demonstrate.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because Tabulator formatters are visual only, they do not affect the underlying data used for sorting and filtering.

If you want the updated value to be included in the sort then you need to use a ***mutator*** not a formatter.

This will then convert the underlying data and will work when sorted:

```js
mutator: function(value) {
    var value = value;
    if (data.Tipo == 'Holfuy') {
        return value * 5;
    } else {
        return value;
    }
},
```

Full details can be found in the [Mutator Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.8/mutators#mutators)

Comment: Thanks, but how i could get cell value for mutator function? As formatter function. Actually I recive a error and tabulator not working

Comment: it is passed into the first argument of the function as the example shows. please read the mutator documentation for greater understanding. (I should mention that i am the chap that wrote Tabulator, so i can guarantee this is the correct approach)